# Are they any good tutorials on how to make animated mud/dirt?

Tags: rigging, particles

This is a project I'm working on that features an industrial factory machine (already modeled out), but inside the machine a mud-like substance is poured in, and subsequently slowly pushed through the cylinder shape inside of the machine.

Are they any tutorials out there showing how to make a mud substance that animates/moves?

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of fluid simulation tutorials that can get you started. You're going to want a high viscosity fluid to emulate mud. You could then set up your machine to be a collider in the simulation.

[Here is a tutorial that covers the basics of fluid simulation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OGnsu16yX0)

You could also augment your simulation with creative use of metaballs and particles.

[Here is a simple tutorial that covers the very basics of metaballs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rumYWmWTkQQ)

[Here is a more advanced tutorial that covers metaballs and particles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3pI7ycYN3A)

Finally, here are a couple more fluid simulation tutorials:

[Create Splashes in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVwfEHtLiyI)

[Realistic Fluid Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmw-BTCbWMw)

Comment: this is great - thanks. I will report back on my developments

Comment: It has been almost a year. Did you have any progress? Did this all work out for you?